# Find the highest 5% of values, using a rolling average, over time and by two separate conditions

Tags: r

**DATA STRUCTURE**

My data (a small sample of the wider dataset) is structured as follows:

```
Individ <- data.frame(Participant = c("Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", 
                                      "Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry","Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul"),
                      Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                      Condition = c("Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", 
                                    "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr"),
                      Location = c("Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Away", "Away", "Away", "Away", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", 
                                   "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Away", "Away", "Away", "Away", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home"),
                      Power = c(400, 250, 180, 500, 300, 450, 600, 512, 300, 500, 450, 200, 402, 210, 130, 520, 310, 451, 608, 582, 390, 570, NA, NA))
```

**MY PROBLEM**

I wish to quantify the following:

- A rolling average of `Power` over a 2, 3 and 4 second window.
- Calculate the above for each `Participant` under each (separate) combination of `Condition` and `Location`. For example, calculate a 2 second rolling average of `Power` for Bill during the Placebo `Condition` and at the Home `Location`. Repeat this and calculate power over a 3 and 4 second rolling average. Repeat again for the Expr and Away `Condition` plus `Location`, respectively.
- Find the highest 5% of `Power` for each rolling average (2, 3 and 4 second windows) under each `Condition` and `Location`. For example, find the highest 5% over a 2 second rolling average for Bill under the Placebo `Condition` and at a Home `Location`. Repeat this for a 3 and 4 second rolling average. Repeat again for the Expr and Away `Condition` plus `Location`, respectively.
- How do I deal with the `NA`'s?

**WHAT I HAVE ATTEMPTED**

I can calculate this for each `Participant` under the differing `Condition` and `Location` by calling them out separately For example:

```
require(zoo)
# Call out all the data for "Bill"
my.data.frame <- Individ[(Individ$Participant == "Bill"), ]
# Call out data for "Placebo" condition only
my.data.frame <- my.data.frame[(my.data.frame$Condition == "Placebo"), ]
# Iterate over the "Power" column and compute a 2, 3 and 4 sec rolling average
my.data.frame$TwoSec <- rollapply(my.data.frame[, 5], width = 2, function(...) {round(mean(...), digits = 1)}, partial = TRUE)
my.data.frame$ThreeSec <- rollapply(my.data.frame[, 5], width = 3, function(...) {round(mean(...), digits = 1)}, partial = TRUE)
my.data.frame$FourSec <- rollapply(my.data.frame[, 5], width = 4, function(...) {round(mean(...), digits = 1)}, partial = TRUE)
```

However, this is time intensive and labour intensive. Plus I am stuck on how to calculate the top 5%.

**CONSTRAINTS**

My actual dataset is 3,062, 143 obs. with over 50 participants under these differing conditions. The `Time` that `Power` is collected over is > 900 seconds (hence the requirement for a rolling average). Ideally, a solution that is quick and not computationally expensive would be ideal.

I understand this is a lengthy question consisting of many smaller parts. Please advise me if I need to clarify further, or break this question down into several separate questions. Thank you.

Comment: Post is not very clear, please add expected output.

Answer (score 0):

**This post will be edited depending on the OPs possible clarification:**

If you are asking for the maximums for only 1, 2, 3 second intervals:

This is probably not the best way, but it should work.

**Step 1: Filter set for only 1, 2, and 3**

```
library(dplyr)
Individ1 <- Individ %>% filter( Time == 1 | Time == 2 | Time == 3) %>% select ( Participant, Time, Condition, Location, Power)
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
Individ1 <- Individ %>% filter( Time <= 3) %>% select ( Participant, Time, Condition, Location, Power)
```

I am unsure if Time is categorical or not, so modify this to your heart's content.

**Step 2: Sort by Power**

```
Individ2 <- Individ1[order(-Individ1$Power),]
```

**Step 3: Calculate the amount of observations in the top 5% of your data**

```
top_percentile <-ceiling(nrow(Individ2)*.05)
```

**Step 4: Select only the first "top_percentile" observations in said dataset.**

```
Individ3<- Individ2[1:top_percentile,]
```

**Step 5: Sorting by Condition, Location**

```
Indvivid4<- Individ3[order(Individ3$Condition, Individ3$Location),]
```

I only created new dataframes for the sake of showing you how each step changes the dataset if you'd like to see it done in the r environment. Just delete the numbers if you only want one data frame.

Please be more detailed if this is not what you are asking for. I probably misunderstood you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am interested in the top 5% of power calculated over a 3 second period, not necessarily the first three seconds. For example, it could be Time entries 2, 3 and 4. I shall clarify this in my original post - apologies for the confusion.

Comment: It's probably just me, but what do you mean by top 5% of power calculated for a 3 second  interval? Top 5% of each intervals power's maximum? Do you want to calculate total power in relation to each interval or ... ? Average power? top 5% of all of the intervals maximums? There are a pleahora of things I can think of that you are trying to summarize here.Try to post what you would like as a result, by indenting it. That would help me and others here potentially.

Comment: I suggest re-explaining the OP, my answer isn't great at all, and giving me the check mark doesn't seem right. I'd like to give a better answer.

Comment: No problem, your answer part answered my initial question (hence the tick) but I will clarify the OP for the opportunity to provide a better answer.

Comment: I have edited my post. In regard to your post above, I wish to calculate the top 5% of power for a three second rolling average. I would like to calculate this for each Participant at each of their respective Conditions and Locations. Please let me know if I may clarify further.

Comment: Hey, I've been working on your problem and I just cant seem to get it work. I highly suggest looking at this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644494/applying-rolling-mean-by-group-in-r

Comment: No worries, thank you for directing me to another question. If I do have a solution, I will post it here as an answer. Appreciate your hard work!

Comment: Let me know if the link manages to be of use to you. I'd like to see your solution. Would be useful for me as well as I am interested in this topic.

Comment: Thank you. I have opened a new question as I am part of the way through my answer but am stuck on a section of code. The link is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692701/error-when-calculating-values-greater-than-95-quantile-using-plyr?noredirect=1#comment59063884_35692701

Comment: I have answered this problem and the link you have provided in the other post.