# rolling mean by multiple groups

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, zoo

I am trying to calculate a rolling mean variable by multiple groups. Basically it's the yearly average vote and seat share of party families nested in countries. Here's a sample of the dataset for three countries and more recent years:

```
structure(list(vote_share = c(23.97, 4.5, 4.79, 2.82, 62.51, 
28.98, 10.8, 0.61, 57.12, 15.11, 0.41, 12.85, 18.61, 52.73, 27.26, 
0.49, 11.46, 5.7, 54.28, 21.19, 2.47, 21.18, 54.56, 19.63, 1.86, 
16.49, 61.48, 24.84, 2.25, 11.98, 60.3, 5.7, 3.6, 18.2, 71.5, 
36.9, 17.7, 9, 6.3, 28.5, 35, 7.9, 7.7, 15.3, 32.9, 24.3, 5.6, 
13.7, 14.7, 39.3, 32.7, 6.5, 10, 22.1, 26.8, 35.4, 6.2, 7.6, 
22.9, 26.6, 30.8, 5.5, 8, 16.3, 36.6, 37.7, 8.5, 7.9, 6.7, 38.1, 
45.3, 7.7, 11.2, 1.2, 33.7, 36.38, 6.12, 16.48, 39.37, 39.9, 
6.2, 13, 1.44, 37.8, 35.2, 7.9, 11, 2.9, 40.2, 30.66, 7.21, 12.94, 
5.7, 42.72, 31.01, 9.23, 12.61, 12.86, 33.32), seat_share = c(24.6666660308838, 
4.66666668653488, 4.66666662693024, 2, 63.9999988079071, 30, 
10.6666667461395, 0, 59.3333343267441, 15.3333330154419, 0, 12.6666665077209, 
18.666667342186, 53.333332657814, 28, 0, 11.3333334922791, 5.33333349227905, 
55.3333333730698, 22, 1.33333337306976, 21.3333325386047, 55.3333343267441, 
20, 1.33333337306976, 16.6666665077209, 61.999999165535, 25.3333339691162, 
1.33333337306976, 12.6666667461395, 60.6666675806046, 6, 3.33333325386047, 
18.6666660308838, 72.0000003576279, 40.6060600280762, 19.3939399719238, 
8.48484861850739, 6.06060600280762, 25.4545446634293, 39.3939399719238, 
6.66666650772095, 5.45454549789429, 15.151515007019, 33.3333333730698, 
26.0606060028076, 6.06060600280762, 13.9393939971924, 15.7575759887695, 
38.1818188428879, 36.0946731567383, 6.50887584686279, 8.87574005126953, 
22.4852066040039, 26.035502910614, 37.8698234558105, 6.50887584686279, 
6.50887584686279, 24.2603549957275, 24.8520716428757, 32.5443801879883, 
5.91715955734253, 4.73372763395309, 17.1597633361816, 39.6449699401855, 
39.5415458679199, 8.8825216293335, 4.58452701568604, 7.16332387924194, 
39.8280801773071, 46.1318054199219, 7.73638963699341, 11.4613180160522, 
0, 34.6704869270325, 37.535816192627, 5.15759325027466, 16.9054441452026, 
40.4011468887329, 41.2607460021973, 6.30372476577759, 13.4670486450195, 
0, 38.9684820175171, 37.2492828369141, 8.30945587158203, 11.747850894928, 
0, 42.6934089660645, 32.0916900634766, 6.59025764465332, 12.6074500083923, 
5.73065900802612, 42.9799423217773, 32.3782234191895, 6.30372476577759, 
13.1805157661438, 14.040114402771, 34.0974206924438), el_date = structure(c(8888, 
8888, 8888, 8888, 8888, 10352, 10352, 10352, 10352, 11822, 11822, 
11822, 11822, 11822, 12074, 12074, 12074, 12074, 12074, 13474, 
13474, 13474, 13474, 14769, 14769, 14769, 14769, 15595, 15595, 
15595, 15595, 17240, 17240, 17240, 17240, 8656, 8656, 8656, 8656, 
8656, 10120, 10120, 10120, 10120, 10120, 11575, 11575, 11575, 
11575, 11575, 13038, 13038, 13038, 13038, 13038, 14501, 14501, 
14501, 14501, 14501, 15957, 15957, 15957, 15957, 15957, 7927, 
7927, 7927, 7927, 7927, 9026, 9026, 9026, 9026, 9026, 10489, 
10489, 10489, 10489, 11945, 11945, 11945, 11945, 11945, 13408, 
13408, 13408, 13408, 13408, 14871, 14871, 14871, 14871, 14871, 
16327, 16327, 16327, 16327, 16327), class = "Date"), family = c("Left", 
"Other", "Radical Left", "Radical Right", "Right", "Left", "Radical Left", 
"Radical Right", "Right", "Left", "Other", "Radical Left", "Radical Right", 
"Right", "Left", "Other", "Radical Left", "Radical Right", "Right", 
"Left", "Other", "Radical Left", "Right", "Left", "Other", "Radical Left", 
"Right", "Left", "Other", "Radical Left", "Right", "Left", "Other", 
"Radical Left", "Right", "Left", "Other", "Radical Left", "Radical Right", 
"Right", "Left", "Other", "Radical Left", "Radical Right", "Right", 
"Left", "Other", "Radical Left", "Radical Right", "Right", "Left", 
"Other", "Radical Left", "Radical Right", "Right", "Left", "Other", 
"Radical Left", "Radical Right", "Right", "Left", "Other", "Radical Left", 
"Radical Right", "Right", "Left", "Other", "Radical Left", "Radical Right", 
"Right", "Left", "Other", "Radical Left", "Radical Right", "Right", 
"Left", "Other", "Radical Left", "Right", "Left", "Other", "Radical Left", 
"Radical Right", "Right", "Left", "Other", "Radical Left", "Radical Right", 
"Right", "Left", "Other", "Radical Left", "Radical Right", "Right", 
"Left", "Other", "Radical Left", "Radical Right", "Right"), country = c("NLD", 
"NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", 
"NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", 
"NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", 
"NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NOR", "NOR", 
"NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", 
"NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", 
"NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", "NOR", 
"NOR", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", 
"SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", 
"SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", 
"SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE"), year = c(1994, 
1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 1991, 1991, 
1991, 1991, 1991, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014)), .Names = c("vote_share", 
"seat_share", "el_date", "family", "country", "year"), row.names = c(NA, 
-99L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Even though it was asked multiple times, I am not very sure how to do this. I've tried to follow [this suggestion](https://danieljhocking.wordpress.com/2014/12/03/lags-and-moving-means-in-dplyr/) with:

```
countries = countries %>%
  group_by(country, family, year) %>%
  arrange(country, family, year) %>%
  mutate(vote.avg = rollmean(x = vote_share, 5, align = "right", fill = NA))
```

It did not work. Then I tried to follow [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644494/applying-rolling-mean-by-group-in-r) with:

```
countries$avg_vote <- ave(countries$vote_share, c(countries$country, countries$family),
                    FUN= function(x) rollmean(x, k=5, na.pad=T) )
```

It did not work, it gives a similar error both times:

> ```
> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : k <= n is not TRUE
> ```

so I assume I do not specify the groups correctly. I have tried multiple other ways, and could not figure it out. It would be important that the means do not "flow" over between country and party family groups.

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: What the error states is that you are trying to do a rolling mean of window of 5, in a dataset that has only 3 values - Try `rollmean(c(1, 5, 4), 5)`

Comment: but I get the same error if I put a width of 2, so I guess it has to do with how the groups are specified.

Comment: `rollmean(c(1, 5, 4), 2)` works fine. If you mean your full data set, then that means that you have groups with only 1 entry. Maybe do an if statement or filter out those groups first and then try again.

Comment: thanks! you were right, it was a problem of too few cases in some of the groups, I've solved it now. If you want to write up a response I am happy to accept it. Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Try this: `mutate(vote.avg = rollapplyr(vote_share, 5, mean, fill = NA, partial = TRUE))`